Should the [nsopengl] tag be removed?
First, there is no such thing as NSOpenGL. There is NSOpenGLView, NSOpenGLContext, NSOpenGLPixelFormat, and that's pretty much it for the NSOpenGL* "namespace". nsopengl only has 8 questions, while the nsopenglview tag has around 80. Six out of eight questions apply strongly to NSOpenGLView and most of them are already tagged with nsopenglview.
Should this tag be removed? Please correct this question if it's phrased wrong.
